# MFC CStatusBar not Topmost into resizable CDialog

Tags: mfc, dialog, window-resize

I made an MFC application based on a dialog. Into this, I added a CStatusBar into bottom of the dialog addin this code into CMyDialog::InitDIalog() :

```
//Create status bar 
BOOL bReturn = m_wndStatusBar.Create(this);     
m_wndStatusBar.SetIndicators(indicators,1); 

//    Find the Size of Dialog box
CRect rect;                                        
GetClientRect(&rect);         

//    Size the two panes 
m_wndStatusBar.SetPaneInfo(0,IDD_INDICATOR_STATUS, SBPS_NORMAL, rect.Width());

//    This is where we actually draw it 
RepositionBars( AFX_IDW_CONTROLBAR_FIRST, AFX_IDW_CONTROLBAR_LAST, IDD_INDICATOR_STATUS ) ;
```

Note in the dialog editor, I had to keep some space at the bottom for the status bar. Work fine so far, status bar is correctly displayed :

[image]

BUT problem occurs when I resize the dialog. I put this code into CMyDialog::OnSize() :

```
RepositionBars( AFX_IDW_CONTROLBAR_FIRST, AFX_IDW_CONTROLBAR_LAST, IDD_INDICATOR_STATUS) ; 
m_wndStatusBar.SetForegroundWindow();
```

The position of the CStatusBar window is correctly adapted... but status bar is displayed behind other controls.

[image]

Any idea how to solve this ? Why the call to SetForegroungWindow() is not working in this case ?

Comment: But anyway, the situation in the second image shouldn't happen, the group box containing "Mode : NOMINAL" and the status bar overlap, even if the status bar is on top of the group box. You should handle the WM_GETMINMAXINFO message and restrict the minimum size in order to prevent overlapping, then it wouln't matter anymore that the status bar isn't the top window.

Comment: BTW: [`SetForegroundWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539(v=vs.85).aspx) is not what you need here, you need [`SetWindowPos`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1yzfz6d.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the hint Michael. That's right, with a combination of SetWindowPos to resize some of my controls and WM_GETMINMAXINFO that limit the resize, I can make something working. But on my case I have some graphical drawing on the right and I don' t care if I lose part of the dialog on left on resize. So that's why I asked how to put the "status bar" control in tom of my dialog controls on my case to have this "disapear" effect. I was expecting SetForegroundWindow to do it... that's my main question there.

Comment: Well, `SetWindowPos` can also be used to change the z-order (that's what you want) of windows,  on only for changing the position and size of windows.